# Add checkbox to options in selectize js

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Is it possible to add a checkbox to the option renderers so that users can select and deselect the item by clicking on the checkbox.

I was able to add the checkbox by adding

```
<input type = "checkbox">
```

to the option renderers. But I have no clue about how to handle the click function and add the selected value to the header. I have tried the remove_button plugin. But thats not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `toggle` event and a publications input:

```
$('.Publications input[type=checkbox]')
```

then toggle that when clicked.